# Amazon EC2 Instance Type Upgrade

Tags: amazon-ec2

I am a newbie to ec2 and have been using a micro instance for the past couple weeks.  I am interested in "upgrading" to a small or large instance, is there a way I can do this using the AWS Console? If so, what happens to the EBS storage the micro image uses?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the control panel:

- stop your instance
- create an AMI
- start new machine from this AMI, this time selecting another instance type

Answer (score -1):

You can't do this through the console, as far as I know -- you need to use the API. The EBS storage won't be affected.

Comment: How do I go about using the API? Can I connect to my instance using ssh and call the API from there?

Comment: Sure you can, anytime you launch an AMI you can pick the instance type in the top right.

Comment: You can now, but you couldn't back in January 2011. Amazon keep upgrading the web console's functionality.